# FOSOauthServerBundle how to make signed call

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, fosoauthserverbundle

I have set up FOSOauthServerBundle, I have my api and access token
For now when I call /api?access_token=.... all I see is login page.
My security.yml:

```
    security:
        firewalls:
            main:
                pattern: ^/
                form_login:
                    provider: fos_userbundle
                    csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                logout:       true
                anonymous:    true
            api:
                pattern: ^/api
                fos_oauth: true
                stateless: true
            oauth_authorize:
                pattern: ^/oauth/v2/auth
                form_login:
                    provider: fos_userbundle
                    check_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login_check
                    login_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login
                anonymous: true
            oauth_token:
                pattern: ^/oauth/v2/token
                security: false

        access_control:
            ...
            - { path: ^/api, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ] }
```

Comment: is your /api path protected by another firewall in security.yml? if you could show more of your security.yml, it would help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what could cause that however I would recommend to replace following firewall:

```
main:
    pattern: ^/
    ...
```

with

```
main:
    pattern: ^/login$
    ...
```

This will map your firewall only for login page.